# Merge sort with array lists in java

Tags: java, arraylist, mergesort

So for homework I have to write a program that mergeSorts with array lists from a code that works with regular arrays, I was just wondering if someone could help me figure out where I went wrong, because my code throws a ton of NULL POINTER exceptions, and I have tried to fix them, but when I fix one it goes to another...and so on....

Thanks!
My code:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static ArrayList<Integer> helper;
private static int number;
public static void sort(ArrayList<Integer> myNumbers){
    for(int i=0; i<myNumbers.size();i++){
        numbers.add(myNumbers.get(i));
    }
    //numbers=myNumbers;
    number = myNumbers.size()-1;

    mergesort(0, number -1);
}
private static void mergesort(int low, int high){
    //check if low is smaller than high, if not then the array is sorted
    if(low<high){
        //get the index of the element which is in the middle
        int middle=low+(high-low)/2;
        //sort the left side of the array
        mergesort(low, middle);
        //sort the right side of the array
        mergesort(middle +1, high);
        //combine them both
        merge(low, middle, high);
    }
}
private static void merge(int low, int middle, int high){
    //copy both parts into the helper array
    for(int i=high;i>low;i++){
        helper.add((numbers.get(i)));
    }

    int i=low;
    int j=middle+1;
    int k=low;
    //copy the smallest myNumbers from either the left or right side back to the original array
    while(i<middle  && j<high){
        if(helper.get(i)< helper.get(j)){
            numbers.set(k,(helper.get(i)));
            i++;
        }
        else{
            numbers.set(k,(helper.get(j)));
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    //copy the rest of the left side of the array into target array
    while(i<middle){
        numbers.set(k,helper.get(i));
        k++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at BinarySearch.merge(BinarySearch.java:61)
at BinarySearch.mergesort(BinarySearch.java:55)
at BinarySearch.mergesort(BinarySearch.java:51)
at BinarySearch.mergesort(BinarySearch.java:51)
at BinarySearch.mergesort(BinarySearch.java:51)
at BinarySearch.mergesort(BinarySearch.java:51)
at BinarySearch.mergesort(BinarySearch.java:51)
at BinarySearch.mergesort(BinarySearch.java:51)
at BinarySearch.sort(BinarySearch.java:43)
at BinarySearch.main(BinarySearch.java:25)
```

Comment: Your `helper` is not initialized. That's causing you trouble

Answer (score 1):

It tries to access helper field in merge function which is not created.

Also I think you should remove static keyword from all functions/fields.

private static ArrayList helper;

to

private static ArrayList helper= new ArrayList();

Comment: I can't remove static because it is in the same class as my main

Comment: if you try to run it multiple times, numbers and helper will have previous values so you would need to clear list before running it again, also best way is to move this functionality to a new class MergeSort and in main class create new instance of MergeSort and call desired functions.

Answer (score 1):

here's the culprit:

```
for(int i=high;i>low;i++){
    helper.add((numbers.get(i)));
}
```

use `for(int i=high; i>=low; i--) {` instead.

Answer (score 0):

blackuprise pointed out your two problems.

Your merge implementation has another problem, which could make your merge result wrong. At the end of your merge method, you have:

```
//copy the rest of the left side of the array into target array
while...
```

how can you so sure every time all right side of the array would be merged, and only left part has elements left?  (strange sentence ^_^ left part has sth. left.)

You should check for the right side too. or use a `SENTINEL` to avoid the "rest" checking.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I haven't taken java that long.

Comment: @user2319595 the merge method will merge two sub-arrays. if you are lucky, after your first `while` the two sub-arrays have no elements left. however either of them could have elements left. you have to handle the rest elements, add them to your target/merged array. You just checked the left side, you didn't check the right side. take a look this code, I had two merge methods, with or without sentinel: https://github.com/sk1418/jalgorithm/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kent/algorithm/sorting/MergeSort.java

Comment: @user2319595 it depends on the input array. As I said, if you are lucky, your mergesort will give correct result. but not always. :) make some test cases, you will see.

Comment: haha thanks! Yea, i have a program that puts 100 random ints in a text file and turns that into an arraylist for my tester

Comment: But right now it is returning a bunch of zeroes and the number 26 about 12 times then 45 and stopping

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve a merge sort using your algorithm for an academic use that the given answer was a good one, else if you are interested in an implementation that Guava already has, then here it is: [guava Iterators](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#mergeSorted%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Answer (score 0):

public class Merged

```
public  static void sort(List<String>result )
{

     for( i=0;i<result.size();i++)
     {
        try{

          try{


         if(result.get(i).compareTo(result.get(i+1))>0)
             {
             String aux=result.get(i);
             result.set(i, result.get(i+1));
             result.set(i+1, aux);

             }


             }catch(NullPointerException e){}
          }catch(ClassCastException z){}

        }
    }


public static void main(String[]args) throws ClassNotFoundException
{ 
    String[]resultentry=new String[100];
    int index;//nr de elemente din vectorul de stringuri//
    int i;

    try{
   //declare files and lists//
    BufferedReader firstfile;
    BufferedReader secondfile;


    firstfile=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lista1.txt"));
    secondfile=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lista2.txt"));;


         firstentry=firstfile.readLine();
        secondentry=secondfile.readLine();

        while(firstentry!=null&&secondentry!=null)
        {
        firstlist.add(firstentry);
        firstentry=firstfile.readLine();

        secondlist.add(secondentry) ;
        secondentry=secondfile.readLine();

         }


     }catch(IOException exp){}


     try{

    java.util.Collections.sort(firstlist);
    System.out.println("First list sorted :"+ firstlist);

    java.util.Collections.sort(secondlist);
    System.out.println("Second list sorted"+secondlist);


    firstlist.addAll(secondlist);
    java.util.Collections.sort(firstlist);

    System.out.println("Result  list sorted "+" "+firstlist);

    }catch(ClassCastException b){}

   }

}`
```